# Check wether words from a list are inside a string of another list Python

Tags: python, string, list, conditional-statements, any

So I tried getting all the headlines of the New York Times homepage and wanted to see how many times a certain word has been mentioned. In this particular case, I wanted to see how many headlines mentioned either the Coronavirus or Trump. This is my code but it won't work as 'number' remains the integer I give it before the while loop.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.nytimes.com'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
a = soup.findAll("h2", class_="esl82me0")

for story_heading in a:
    print(story_heading.contents[0])

lijst = ["trump", "Trump", "Corona", "COVID", "virus", "Virus", "Coronavirus", "COVID-19"]
number = 0
run = 0

while run < len(a)+1:
    run += 1
     if any(lijst in s for s in a)
        number += 1

print("\nTrump or the Corona virus have been mentioned", number, "times.")
```

So I basically want the variable 'number' to increase by 1 if a headline (which is an entry in the list a) has the word Trump or Coronavirus or both in them.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: This doesn't count as an answer, given that I'm not giving you a complete solution, but typically you would do the following:

1. Fetch the contents.
2. Cast all text to lowercase so that the matching can be efficient.
3. Tokenize the text into individual entities. Good options are SpaCy and NLTK.
4. A question of counting and sorting. `collections.Counter` would do the trick for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, I recommend putting more thought into naming variables. I like how you tried to print the story headings. The line `if any(lijst in s for s in a)` does not do what you think it should: you need to instead iterate over each word in a single h2. The `any` function is just a short hand for the following:

```
def any(iterable):
    for element in iterable:
        if element:
            return True
    return False
```

In other words, you're trying to see if an entire list is in an h2 element, which will never be true. Here is an example fix.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.nytimes.com'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
h2s = soup.findAll("h2", class_="esl82me0")

for story_heading in h2s:
    print(story_heading.contents[0])

keywords = ["trump", "Trump", "Corona", "COVID", "virus", "Virus", "Coronavirus", "COVID-19"]
number = 0
run = 0

for h2 in h2s:
    headline = h2.text
    words_in_headline = headline.split(" ")
    for word in words_in_headline:
        if word in keywords:
            number += 1
print("\nTrump or the Corona virus have been mentioned", number, "times.")
```

Output

```
Trump or the Corona virus have been mentioned 7 times.
```

Comment: It's so satisfying to see the logic behind code and now I finally understand what I did wrong. Thank you so much! :-)